# (Visual Studio Code & NodeJS) - Could not install typings files for JavaScript language features?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, visual-studio-code

I had installed latest NVM and used it to install NodeJS (macOS). Everything was okay, NodeJS ran normally. But when I started VS Code the following message appeared:

> Could not install typings files for JavaScript language features. Please ensure that NPM is installed or configure 'typescript.npm' in your user settings

So I tried to find more official information from VS Code team. They said to insert the path to the npm executable file in the `typescript.npm` setting.

I used  `$ which npm` to find the npm directory :

```
/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.3.0/bin/npm
```

but there is no executable file there. I also tried to insert this address into VSCode typescript.npm setting but it did not work.

My question is, where can I find the npm executable file address on macOS to insert into this `typescript.npm` setting so the error wouldn't pop up anymore ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Releated VSCode issue: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24961#issuecomment-297774505) Maybe it will help you.